# sed + match string in file and replace line that include value after separator

Tags: linux, bash, sed

in  `/etc/barman.conf` configuration file

we have the following line

```
retention_policy = RECOVERY WINDOW OF 7 days
```

in our bash script we want to add sed command or maybe Perl one liners , that will change the integer value between the words "**OF**" and "**days**"

number 7 in above example - could be any integer number and should be replace according to new value - $NUM_OF_DAY

we tries with following option , that replaced the value after “=” separator but without success

```
NUM_OF_DAYS=23

sed '/retention_policy/!b; n; s/RECOVERY WINDOW OF [0-9]+ days/RECOVERY WINDOW OF $NUM_OF_DAYS days/g'  /etc/barman.conf
```

or maybe the best option is completely delete the words/value after “=” separator and re-set the new line -  `RECOVERY WINDOW OF $NUM_OF_DAY days`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ num_of_days=23
$ sed -E "/^(retention_policy[^[:digit:]]*)[[:digit:]]+/s//\1$num_of_days/" /etc/barman.conf
retention_policy = RECOVERY WINDOW OF 23 days
```

Comment: I tried this option with -i flag in order to update the file but value "7" was not change    ( sed -iE "/^(retention_policy[^[:digit:]]*)[[:digit:]]+/s//\1$num_of_days/" /etc/barman.conf )

Comment: @Judy Try it the other way round (and always make a backup file) `sed -Ei.bak "/^(retention_policy[^[:digit:]]*)[[:digit:]]+/s//\1$num_of_days/" /etc/barman.conf`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how strict your input file line syntax is, but if `^retention_policy` is used for line matching, and number is between `OF`  and  `days` strings, you may try something like:

```
$ NUM_OF_DAYS=42
$ sed -E "/^retention_policy/ s/(.*OF )[0-9]+( days.*)$/\1$NUM_OF_DAYS\2/" /tmp/foo.conf
```

or the simpler alternative :

```
$ NUM_OF_DAYS=42
$ sed -E "s/(^retention.*OF )[0-9]+( days.*)$/\1$NUM_OF_DAYS\2/" /tmp/foo.conf
```

With the output:

```
$ cat /tmp/foo.conf
retention_policy = no match
retention_policy = RECOVERY WINDOW OF 7 days
no match
$ sed -E "/^retention_policy/ s/(.*OF )[0-9]+( days.*)$/\1$NUM_OF_DAYS\2/" /tmp/foo.conf
retention_policy = no match
retention_policy = RECOVERY WINDOW OF 42 days
no match
$ sed -E "s/(^retention.*OF )[0-9]+( days.*)$/\1$NUM_OF_DAYS\2/" /tmp/foo.conf
retention_policy = no match
retention_policy = RECOVERY WINDOW OF 42 days
no match
```